# What is the least-bad way to invest a Simple IRA with heavy fees around every corner?

Tags: united-states, ira, etf, vanguard

Given the following situation:

- an employer-offered "Simple IRA" run by a major brokerage with 1% gross pay matching;
- No near-future feasible opportunity to invest the Simple IRA contribution in a no-load index fund because of high minimums;
- the option of buying A or C shares of virtually any mutual fund available, so long as it isn't no-load;
- a transaction fee of $50 per ten shares on stocks, including ETFs;
  and no option to go somewhere other than the specific brokerage without forgoing the 1% matching,

**What is the optimal strategy in this situation for someone who ideally would invest in a passive index fund like Vanguard's VFINX with minimal frictional costs?**

- ETFs, even though they have the relatively high transaction fee? If so, how should the transactions be spaced so as to minimize the frictional costs?
- A mutual fund with a load of some sort, even though they will have fees of their own and (AFAIK) have poorer performance than an index fund and generally are not passive?
- Forgo the matching and just save a certain percentage of income in an index fund privately?
- Some other strategy altogether?

**Edit:** *generalized the question, took out the explanation of A and C shares (someone please let me know if they are not standardized and thus the brokerage might have a unique fee structure for them that would change the optimal strategy). Not looking for specific buy/sell recommendations, e.g. I just want something as close to index funds like VFINX or VOO as possible. If it turns out the best strategy is a brokerage-exclusive discount on iShares' IVV, that works just as well. Thanks for all the responses so far.*

Comment: are you sure you have to pay the loads? My Mom had a ML 401k and the load was waived inside the 401k (as it should be since there's no salesperson to get the commission), even though it was a bunch of load funds. The funds still had high expenses of course.

Comment: I commend you on writing a *very* detailed question.  Please note, though, that specific buy/sell recommendations are off-topic for this site.  Please consult the FAQ using the link to the left of the search box at the top of the page.

Comment: @Jordan Can you make your question a bit more generic so it might help other people in similar situations?

Comment: Complete side note: Only 1%? *More*.

Comment: @C. Ross: If 1% is what it takes to get the full company match, **do not** put any more money than you have to into what sounds like a plan with excessive fees. Much better to put extra money into an outside/independent IRA where there aren't such crazy fees.

Comment: @bstpierre True.  Still 1% isn't a retirement plan by itself.

Comment: @George Marian I don't believe @Jordan is asking for "specific buy/sell recommendations" in the sense that violates the FAQ.  I believe he is asking, "How can I passively and sensibly invest in my 401k?".  I'm no mod, but to me that sounds different and on-topic.

Comment: @Michael Agreed.  His first question in the original version was borderline, because it only implicitly asked if the VOO ETF was a good substitute for the VFINX.  I should have been more specific myself by suggesting that he reword the question so that it made that point more obvious.

Comment: I have this same situation and question, except that it's a Charles Schwab account, so thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $50 fee is crazy. I'd not miss the match, despite the load fund fees. If you put in $500 and get $500 match, a 5% fee won't kill you. But that's all I'd put in. Invest outside that IRA, as much as you can. 
Sorry, 1% is pretty low, sorry they don't have a low cost 401(k).